# Looking for the name of the cognitive skills test that includes a memory test involving the names of cartoon aliens

Tags: test, iq, cognitive, cognitive-development

I took a cca. 60-minute-long cognitive test about 10 years ago but I can't remember its name (haha...) But I can remember a part that was a memory test involving cartoon aliens and another part when I had to listen to and tell apart very slightly different-sounding gibberish words. I don't have contact anymore with the psychologist who administered the test and I couldn't identify the test based on my memories. My guess is that it could have been a subset of the Woodcock-Johnson but I'm not sure.

Can you recognize the test based on my rather incomplete description?